# Google Cloud Storage FUSE Adapter: Use Case?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

The [README documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) says:

> Please treat gcsfuse as beta-quality software.

My question is, would GCS Fuse ever be deployed in a production application? In other words, what is the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCS FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) allows you to mount Cloud Storage buckets as file systems on Linux or macOS systems.

As gcsfuse is "beta-quality software", It is not recommended for production use for the time being.

A more reliable alternative for file operations between an instance's or on-prem's file system and GCS buckets, It would be better to use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think that is right. So GCS Fuse is for development only?

Comment: Yes, as it could cause you Production issues when it fails and a fix may not be readily available

Comment: Is gcsfuse being ported to use native FileProvider APIs so it's compatible with Ventura?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, an active development is going on to make [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) production ready. Ref - [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/pulse/monthly)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, would GCS Fuse ever be deployed in a production application? In other words, what is the use case?

No, never - but that's nothing to do with it being GCS or Fuse, it's the Beta bit that answers that question for me.

This site is specifically for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins and system designers - it's the first thing we say in the help pages, and most if not all pro's in this field have a series of priorities that we stick to.

The most important role I, and many others believe we, have is not to keep live service up 100%, that's very important but it's second on the list, the most important one is to ensure live service CAN be brought up in the event of something stopping live service.

There's no point in keeping a system running if it can't be restarted, either in-place or at say a DR site.

And the concept of using beta, thus unsupported/badly-supported, software flies in the face of all of this.

We need our infrastructure, whether hardware or software, to be supportable - because we need help, often, nobody can do everything on their own (that's what this site is for), it's a team-sport, and thus we need to know our environments can be supported - by us and by the support network around us.

Beta doesn't cut it, it's not professional, not until it's fully supported, and then it's not beta :)